# VSCode Debugging Eigen::VectorXd

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, eigen3, natvis

When I'm debuging in vsCode (on Linux) I want to see what my Eigen::VectorXd actually has in Store. So I tried it with this Eigen.natvis https://github.com/cdcseacave/Visual-Studio-Visualizers/blob/master/Eigen.natvis

and the launch.json file looks like this

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "g++-9 - Build and debug active file",
        "visualizerFile": "${workspaceFolder}/natvis/Eigen.natvis",
        "showDisplayString": true,
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}/bin/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++-9 build active file",
        "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
    }
]
}
```

but the the the Debug Window still only shows this
[Run and Debug Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVb2f.png)

and the DebugConsole isn't very helpfull
[Debug Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etfl1.png)

In short, i wish for an easy way to see all variables of the Eigen::VectorXd inside the "Run and Debug Window"

Answer (score 1):

As written in [Developer's Corner](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Developer%27s_Corner) and [Visual-Studio-Visualizers at github](https://github.com/cdcseacave/Visual-Studio-Visualizers) Eigen debug visualizers is for Visual Studio and not for VS Code.

To benefit from the Visual Studio visualizers, you must be using Visual Studio (e.g. version 2022).
For more help on the Visual Studio Visualizers, see [learn.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/debugger/create-custom-views-of-native-objects?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN)